# how to replace the deprecated cc_content_scale_factor()

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

My platform is cocos2D V3.x  and iOS.

I am using CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() function to append to detect device requirement and apply prefix accordingly but it showing

cc_content_scale_factor() is deprecated.

```
   if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 2 )
            lstrNameToReturn = [lstrNameToReturn stringByAppendingString:@"-ipadhd"];
        else
            lstrNameToReturn = [lstrNameToReturn stringByAppendingString:@"-ipad"];
    }
    else
    {
        if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 2 )
            lstrNameToReturn = [lstrNameToReturn stringByAppendingString:@"-hd"];
        else
            lstrNameToReturn = lstrNameToReturn;
    }


/** @def CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR
Factor relating pixel to point coordinates.
*/
extern CGFloat __ccContentScaleFactor;

/// Deprecated in favor of using CCDirector.contentScaleFactor or           CCTexture2D.contentScale depending on usage.

static inline CGFloat DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE
CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()
{
  return __ccContentScaleFactor;
}
```

Comment: It's right there in the code you posted: `/// Deprecated in favor of using CCDirector.contentScaleFactor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (CCDirector.contentScaleFactor == 2) {
    ...
}
```